# Hair particles aren’t the same colors as the model

Tags: hair

[image]I colored my model using vertex paint because the program would crash if I tried to color it any other way, idk if that has anything to do with the issue but once I add hair particles to my model they are black or rainbow colored instead of the model’s colors. Does anyone have a solution?[image]

Comment: It looks like you are in _Particle Edit_ mode. The hair color will not show up in this mode, try switching to _Object Mode_. And please use proper screenshots on this site instead of taking pictures from the screen.

Comment: In object mode it just looks rainbow colored

Comment: Okay, but I'm sorry you are not even having a proper screenshot, show us nothing which mode you are in there, not how these "rainbow colors" look, nothing of the settings, the material setup etc. and I haven't got my crystal ball with me...

Comment: There’s no feature to add an image for me 

Comment: What do you mean "no feature to add an image"? Here? You already added an image. Or do you mean you cannot take a screenshot? Go to Blender's top menu, _Window_ > _Save Screenshot_ or _Save Screenshot (Editor)_

Comment: Here in the comment section, I can only write

Comment: You can edit your question. It is always best to put all necessary information in the question because it might get easily overlooked in the comments.

Comment: Vertex Colors work with particles. I've never used it before but just tried. You have to use the *Attribute* or the *Color Attribute* node for the material in the *Shader Editor*. Feel free to add a screenshot of your material. Also, make sure the correct material is used in the particle render settings.

Comment: Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/294054/edit) your question and click the ["Image" icon in the toolbar](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1083/107598) to upload your image. The link you have posted starts with "file://". It's a local & private link that only you can access.

Comment: there's no toolbar

Comment: It's not here in the comment section but in the question above. There must be a toolbar because you already added the first image to your question. Just upload any new image there.

Comment: Alr I added another image